# Execute stored procedure programmatically inside recursive CTE instead of Cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, common-table-expression

I want to implement recursive CTE instead of following cursor because it takes lot of time to insert data by executing stored procedures programatecally inside cursor especially when there is larger number of records in table. I have tried CTE expression to solve this issue but i was failed to generate same with CTE and cursor really sucks and i totally want to replace it with CTE so is there any way to short out this. Advance thanks.

```
    Declare @Emp_Id As Numeric    
    Declare CurEmpWeekOff cursor for        
    Select Emp_Id From tblEmployee Where Cmp_Id = @Cmp_Id And Branch_Id = @Branch_Id And Emp_WeekOff_Type = 1    

    open CurEmpWeekOff        
    Fetch next From CurEmpWeekOff Into @Emp_Id    
    while @@Fetch_Status = 0        
    Begin        
  If @Is_Sunday = 1    
   Exec [prcEmployee_WeekoffInsert] @Cmp_Id, @Branch_Id, @Emp_Id, @From_Date, 0, '', @Login_Id, 0    
  If @Is_Monday = 1    
   Exec [prcEmployee_WeekoffInsert] @Cmp_Id, @Branch_Id, @Emp_Id, @From_Date, 1, '', @Login_Id, 0    
  If @Is_Tuesday = 1    
   Exec [prcEmployee_WeekoffInsert] @Cmp_Id, @Branch_Id, @Emp_Id, @From_Date, 2, '', @Login_Id, 0    
  If @Is_Wednesday = 1    
   Exec [prcEmployee_WeekoffInsert] @Cmp_Id, @Branch_Id, @Emp_Id, @From_Date, 3, '', @Login_Id, 0    
  If @Is_Thursday = 1    
   Exec [prcEmployee_WeekoffInsert] @Cmp_Id, @Branch_Id, @Emp_Id, @From_Date, 4, '', @Login_Id, 0    
  If @Is_Friday = 1    
   Exec [prcEmployee_WeekoffInsert] @Cmp_Id, @Branch_Id, @Emp_Id, @From_Date, 5, '', @Login_Id, 0    
  If @Is_Saturday = 1    
   Exec [prcEmployee_WeekoffInsert] @Cmp_Id, @Branch_Id, @Emp_Id, @From_Date, 6, '', @Login_Id, 0    

  Fetch next From CurEmpWeekOff Into @Emp_Id    
    End        
    Close CurEmpWeekOff        
    Deallocate CurEmpWeekOff            
   End
```

Comment: Why does this need to be recursive? Can you explain what is the intent of this code?

Comment: I failed to see why you needed to loop. Can you elaborate on the meta data and what you want to achive? The question is too localized.

Comment: well this code executes when admin trying to reset weekoff daywise setting for all employee at that time i need to update main weekoff table as well update employee_weekoff table with current change.

Comment: The problem is your SP works for single @Emp_Id. You can't really replace cursor until you fix that. You need to take logic aout of your [prcEmployee_WeekoffInsert] procedure and change it with set based operation that will do update for all employees at ones. EDIT- and if you need help with that you'll have to share your SP with us.

Comment: my procedure prcEmployee_WeekoffInsert actually contains insert statement for given parameters and one more thing i deletes all data inside employee_weekoff table before start this cursor. All i need is to make execution of prcEmployee_WeekoffInsert for each employee inside CTE if possible ?! hope u get the point and still any confusion than i will share my sp.

Comment: @mayurk No, it's not possible. You can't call SPs from inside CTE. That's not how CTE works, CTE is something like a temp view - it's just to select rows you need. Even if you can make use of it - it's still not going help you speed the process as long as you need to call SP for each employee.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this do?

```
Declare @Emp_Id As Numeric
DECLARE @TempID INT
DECLARE @DayOfWeek INT

If @Is_Sunday = 1    
  SET @DayOfWeek = 1
  If @Is_Monday = 1    
   SET @DayOfWeek = 2

... INSERT REST HERE
  If @Is_Saturday = 1    
   SET @DayOfWeek = 6 


DECLARE #TempEmp TABLE
(
   ID INT IDENTITY,
   EmpID INT
)

INSERT INTO #TempEmp
(
   EmpID
)
Select Emp_Id From tblEmployee Where Cmp_Id = @Cmp_Id And Branch_Id = @Branch_Id And Emp_WeekOff_Type = 1


WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #TempEmp)
BEGIN

    SELECT TOP 1 @TempID = ID, @Emp_ID = EmpID FROM #TempEmp

    Exec [prcEmployee_WeekoffInsert] @Cmp_Id, @Branch_Id, @Emp_Id, @From_Date, @DayOFWeek, '',      @Login_Id, 0 

    DELETE FROM #TempEmp WHERE ID = @TempId
END
```

Comment: I executed this code and it quite improved execution speed but it adding DayOfWeek=6 to every row of employee and u mean "CREATE TABLE #TempEmp" instead of "DECLARE #TempEmp TABLE" right ?! well thanks for posting this ans and i still need modification to satisfy my condition.

Comment: You'll need to update the code that sets the DayOfWeek variable to suit - a case statement probably best.  I just didn't fancy typing it all in here - it just stops you having to repeat the code to call the sproc.

Comment: ya it everytime replace DayOfWeek with last satisfied if condition and thanks again i try to update code and will inform if done! :)

Comment: I would note that comments on the question above are probably valid.  There may be a quicker way to do this using set based operations depending on what is inside your stored procedure (i.e. not calling it multiple times, but writing a new one instead), but can't tell from the outside.